# How can I make HTML list tags fit the sizing that the list items create?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of list items that **together**, fill a 50 by 50 space for example. But the actual `<ul>` tag fills a seemingly random width and height that is unrelated to the position or size of the `<li>` tags that makeup said list.
Here's the CSS for that list and those list items.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example Two</li>
</ul>
```

This gives the `<ul>` tag this sizing
[ul tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOWLj.png)
Even though the individual items have this sizing
[li tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWd84.png)

So how do I get the `<ul>` tag to take up the total sizing of the items?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `float`, use `display:inline-block` instead:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background:pink;
  padding:1em;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: purple
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example Two</li>
</ul>
```